# How to retrieve a special set of data from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a course table which stores students courses taken. Each row of the table is one course.
The columns are :

```
student id, course, term
```

I want to see how many students take course 1 and (course 2 or course 3) and course 4 in term x.

How could I write a SQL statement to perform the query?

Comment: I think you landed in the chapter about `GROUP BY` in your course?

Comment: I can't decide if I should answer this question, hoping that OP will subsequently fail their final exam, or refuse to answer on the grounds that this is obviously homework which OP should figure out for him/her-self. (Note to students - questions which involve `COURSE` or `STUDENT` or other tables which indicate the academic origin of a question are prima facie assumed to be homework. Just so you know...). In the end I suppose I'll just post this comment... (***sigh***)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case` expression that treats 2 and 3 the same, and then count the distinct number of courses per student:

```
SELECT   student_id
FROM     courses
WHERE    course >= 1 AND course <= 4
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING   COUNT (DISTINCT CASE course WHEN 2 THEN 3 ELSE course END) = 3
```

Comment: Good job. The `CASE` expression in the `HAVING` clause is a nice touch. I'm ashamed I didn't think of something like this.  :-)

Comment: Thank you! I will have a try!